Why does round() function in Tcl return integer type?
Tcl offers several math functions like round(), ceil() and floor():
https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm
I recently noticed an interesting "anomaly" regarding the behavior of round() and I'd like to know if there is a deeper reason for this: While ceil() and floor() return floating point type, round() returns an arbitrary precision integer. This can yield surprising results. For example:
% expr {floor(1000.5)/3}
333.3333333333333
% expr {ceil(1000.5)/3}
333.6666666666667
% expr {round(1000.5)/3}
333

Non-finite value arguments behave differently for obvious reason too:
% expr {floor(+inf)}
Inf
% expr {ceil(+inf)}
Inf
% expr {round(+inf)}
integer value too large to represent

Tcl has close ties to the C language which offers similar functions defined in math.h:
float round (float num);
float ceil (float num);
float floor (float num);

However all of them return floating point type, including round(). It seems the majority of languages (e.g. Python) have chosen this path. Is there a reason why round() in Tcl is different?
PS: The Tcl version is 8.6.4

This is documented in the page you linked: If arg is an integer value, returns arg, otherwise converts arg to integer by rounding and returns the converted value. Asking us why the language designers made that decision would be opinion-based, unless one of the members of the language design team happens to be an SO member and happens to see this particular post and happens to remember why that choice was made.

Being a member of Tcl core team might help, but is not required, because the evolution of the Tcl language is very transparent for all users by TIPs (Tcl Improvement Proposals): https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/index.md
The current behavior of round() is a consequence of the (very long) list of TIPs being implemented.
It's no opinion or speculation involved: If round() always had this behavior, even before TIPs existed (around year 2000), this is an accepted answer. If a TIP changed the behavior of round() (which I assume), this TIP explains the reasons, which is accepted answer.

I don't think there's been a behaviour change there for at least 30 years.

Sorry for posting an answer to my own question. But since I meanwhile investigated the topic quite deeply I want to share the results and although I haven't found a definitive answer to the question I think this is as far as one can get:
The round() function was added with Tcl 7.0 dating back to the year 1993. Its implementation appeared in tclExpr.c as:
static int
ExprRoundFunc(clientData, interp, args, resultPtr)
    ClientData clientData;
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    Tcl_Value *args;
    Tcl_Value *resultPtr;
{
    resultPtr->type = TCL_INT;
    if (args[0].type == TCL_INT) {
    resultPtr->intValue = args[0].intValue;
    } else {
    if (args[0].doubleValue < 0) {
        if (args[0].doubleValue <= (((double) (long) LONG_MIN) - 0.5)) {
        tooLarge:
        interp->result = "integer value too large to represent";
        Tcl_SetErrorCode(interp, "ARITH", "IOVERFLOW",
            interp->result, (char *) NULL);
        return TCL_ERROR;
        }
        resultPtr->intValue = (args[0].doubleValue - 0.5);
    } else {
        if (args[0].doubleValue >= (((double) LONG_MAX + 0.5))) {
        goto tooLarge;
        }
        resultPtr->intValue = (args[0].doubleValue + 0.5);
    }
    }
    return TCL_OK;
}

This initial version returned a native integer type. Later, by adding arbitrary precision integers (TIP237) this was changed to arbitrary precision integers:
https://tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/237
The change log does not give a reason why it was chosen to return an integer type. It simply reads:
167. 4/3/93 Changes to expressions:
    ...
    - Expressions now support transcendental and other functions, e.g. sin,
      acos, hypot, ceil, and round.  Can add new math functions with
      Tcl_CreateMathFunc().

The source code does not contain comments describing a reason either. As far as the commit info can be relied upon, it was the decision of the inventor of the language, John Ousterhout himself.
It's interesting to note that most math functions (including ceil() and floor()) simply forwarded to the corresponding C library implementation while round() did not:
#ifndef TCL_NO_MATH
#include <math.h>
#endif
//...

static BuiltinFunc funcTable[] = {
#ifndef TCL_NO_MATH
    {"ceil", 1, {TCL_DOUBLE}, ExprUnaryFunc, (ClientData) ceil},
    {"floor", 1, {TCL_DOUBLE}, ExprUnaryFunc, (ClientData) floor},
// ...
#endif
    {"int", 1, {TCL_EITHER}, ExprIntFunc, 0},
    {"round", 1, {TCL_EITHER}, ExprRoundFunc, 0},
// ...
};

There was a macro TCL_NO_MATH which offered to exclude the C library math functions. Doing this did not disable floating point support however. To be able to convert floating point types to integers, even when excluding the C library math functions, a discrete implementation of round() was required.
The speculative part of the answer is this:
The focus of thinking might have been on doing conversions, not on mimicking C prototypes.
On the one hand it might appeared more convenient to have
set y [expr {round($x)}]

instead of
set y [expr {int(round($x))}]

to get an integer value. On the other hand int() and round() were neighbors in source code. They might have been implemented as "two different ways to convert floating point to integer type" being available even if using TCL_NO_MATH.

Good answer. You've delved into this far deeper than I would have ever done. The only thing I'd add is that we're not about to change this (specifically the behaviour with a single argument, as supporting extra arguments that let it do different things would be possible even though there's no current proposal to do so); it would be needlessly breaking user code.

Interestingly the starting point I came to this question was Tcl 9.0 is doing that (needlessly breaking user code) regarding the int() and entier() function. int() no longer cuts to 32-bits (okay), but entier() gets "deprecated". In other words, the behavior of int() is changing but entier() is no replacement option. So I was looking how to make our codebase work in Tcl 8.x and Tcl 9 without Tcl version used in if..then..else around expr commands.
